# windows Phone 7 - Contact and Calendar UniqueID

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

I need to get UniqueId of Contact and Calendar from Windows Phone 7. I am able to get various properties (e.g. Name, Address etc) but don't get any property to uniquely identify contact and calendar. Is there any property that can be used to uniquely identify contact and calendar?

Answer (score 2):

There is [no property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contact_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) which exposes a unique Id.

Can you use the HashCode instead?

What would be considered a unique contact anyway?
Because of the way contacts can be created from multiple linked accounts the concept of what a "unique" contact should be could be easily misinterpreted.

If you want this because you're creating copies of contacts details I woudl strongly advise against this because of such issues.
You should also consider data privacy very carefully if doing this.